# How to write test in Enzyme to check if connected/smart component exists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme

I have the following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Header
} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import SummaryTable from '../SummaryTable/SummaryTable';
import SummaryFilters from '../SummaryFilters/SummaryFilters';

function TabSummary() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header as="h2">
        Blah blah
      </Header>
      <SummaryFilters />
      <SummaryTable />
    </>
  );
}

export default TabSummary;
```

How can I write a test for this component to check if the SummaryFilter component exists. SummaryFilter is a connected/smart component and the following test:

```
it('should display <SummaryFilters /> when page is first loaded', () => {
  console.log(wrapper.debug());
  expect(wrapper.find('SummaryFilters').exists()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

throws the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(SummaryFilters)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(SummaryFilters) in connect options.
```

What do I need to add/change to run this test successfully?

Appreciate any guidance

Comment: Did you try doing either of the things the error tells you to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `expect(wrapper.find('SummaryFilters').exists()).toBeTruthy();`

to:

```
expect(wrapper.find('Connect(SummaryFilters)').exists()).toBeTruthy();
```

resolved the error and made the test work as expected.